# Adding a WebView in React-Native

Tags: react-native, webview

I tried adding a web view to my app but I'm getting this error:

```
../node_modules/react-native-webview/lib/WebView.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/View' in 'C:\Users\Nikola\node_modules\react-native-webview\lib'
```

This is my minimal code:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {

  return (
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
         <WebView source={{uri:'https://google.com'}} />
         <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong? I used the command npm install react-native-webview but still this error...

Comment: try to use npm i react-native-webview --save and then run yarn, and rebuild the app

Comment: I did it and nothing changed, could you be little more precise?

Comment: when u use  --save when installing a package, it will be saved, also try to use --force, this can be done when installing the package

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error with the latest version of react-native-webview.

Downgrading the version to react-native-webview@11.13.0 solved my issue.

I used yarn add react-native-webview@11.13.0, after uninstalling the previous version.

Comment: actually my error gone .. but webview not available